# Report viewer export and print events

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I need to catch the exporting and printing activities of a report viewer because I need to log the username and the time/date of such activity.
I have had a look at the telerik report viewer events and as well as at the standard asp report viewer but I do not see any of the events that may help me in these regards.

How can I catch the printing  and export activity of the report viewer to embed my code:

```
 Utilities.Record_Transaction("Report_xxx-Exported to Excel " + cname, (string)Session["userName"]);
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

For export you can hide Export control and implement your own adding code you need. Here is first example of doing this from google: http://dinesql.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/report-viewer-control-exporting-reports.html

Same approach you can use for printing - [How to call print from asp.net on a reportviewer control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504747/how-to-call-print-from-asp-net-on-a-reportviewer-control)

Comment: Denis, thanks for your suggestion. I also have considered to move on manual printing/exporting but this means to give up on the embedded features of the report viewer and will be my last resource if I do not find an alternative. For now thanks, if I am forced to move on manual export printing I will give you this answer as accepted.